# Frontend opens desktop apps

Tags: android, web-frontend

How do I make it so that when I open a post on Reddit, for example, I'm prompted to open the installed app and when I press it, it opens? Does the frontend have access to the file system?
Is it possible for the frontend to scan device files, I thought its scope was limited to the web browser only.

I'd be grateful for any explanation

Comment: This is handled by the application itself. It registers itself as a handler of specific URLs and that is how the system displays that prompt. You can read more in official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/